# Issue with deserialization in dropwizard , cannot convert ImmutableList<String> to string list

Tags: java-8, dropwizard, immutables-library

I am using dropwizard 1.1.0 with java 8 features. I am also using Immutables package. I am facing a deserialization issue when trying to convert list of profit centres (string list) from JSON to java equivalent.

**Error**

> Can not find a deserializer for non-concrete Collection type
>   [collection type; class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList,
>   contains [simple type, class java.lang.String]]

**Immutable Java class**

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableReconciliationInputDTO.class)
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableReconciliationInputDTO.class)
public interface ReconciliationInputDTO extends Serializable {

@JsonProperty("date")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
LocalDate asOfDate();

@JsonProperty("label")
String label();

@JsonProperty("entityId")
String entityId();

@JsonProperty("entityName")
String entityName();

@JsonProperty("departments")
List<String> departments();
```

Immutables generated the above DTO to a final class with attributes as below

```
public final class ImmutableReconciliationInputDTO
 implements ReconciliationInputDTO {
private final LocalDate asOfDate;
private final String label;
private final String entityId;
private final String entityName;
private final ImmutableList<String> departments;
```

In my dropwizard application bootstrap I have registered the below modules

```
    bootstrap.getObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    bootstrap.getObjectMapper().registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    bootstrap.getObjectMapper().registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());
```

In my POM.xml I am setting the below as my dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK you should include `guava` as a jackson module also. It is here: [guava-module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-collections)

They also have an example how to integrate it:

```
registerModule(new GuavaModule())
```

Comment: I had already added the guava module earlier and also registered it in my dropwizard application during initialize phase. But that did not help. I tried again post your recommendation but I I am getting the same issue. Jackson isn't able to convert the Immutable list to a corresponding Java collection I suppose. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: @alice: Are you certain that your application only contains one `ObjectMapper` instance? Could it be that you're actually receiving a different one that the one you configured?